# The "thank you for your interest" link is broken

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, stack-overflow-jobs

I clicked a link in an inmail to say I was not interested in a job:

https://careers.stackoverflow.com/email/notinterested/163649/1656211/a0129893e8b64dbfbe86f14df9d53ff3

I ended up at https://stackoverflow.com/jobs with a message that said I could thank them for their interest. When I clicked that link, I got a 404 error at this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/1656211

It said if I thought that was wrong, I should contact the site, and that contact link brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Careers accounts and your SO account is not linked to the one that received this message. This happens occasionally because Careers and SO used to be separate sites. We can merge them for you or move your SO account to the other Careers account.

Let me know in comments and we'll get you fixed up!